# Android Crash - FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, exception, filenotfoundexception

I recently received 6 FileNotFoundException (@CrashActivity:onCreate:135) {main} from one particular device on the same screen.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.CrashActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   **res/layout/crash_layout.xml** from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f03006d
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   **res/layout/crash_layout.xml** from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f03006d
>   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2449)
>   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2404)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:955) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:794) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:296)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1935) at
>   com.example.CrashActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:135) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5258) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
>   ... 11 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML
>   binary file at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method) at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:502)
>   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2431)
>   ... 25 more

My android app is locked in portrait mode.

```xml
<activity
            android:name="com.example.CrashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled"
            android:exported="true"> </activity>
```

It is reported on the line
*setContentView(R.layout.crash_screen);*
in onCreate(..) of the CrashActivity
where **crash_screen.xml** is the layout for the CrashActivity.
**crash_screen.xml** in-turn includes **crash_layout.xml** which has been reported to be missing.
I have checked the R.java for resource ID #0x7f03006d and it points to crash_layout.xml
This is the only instance where I have received this crash and also there has been no code change in the respective activities and layouts in the last few releases.

The complete code is very big so I am adding the code around which the crash was reported.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.crash_screen);
    easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(CrashActivity.this);
    ApplicationSettings.putPref(AppConstants.LAST_COUNT, "0");
    crashScreen = this;
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoRegular.ttf");
    actionbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    actionbarSubtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchedittext);
    searchEditText.setTypeface(tf);

    dialog = new Dialog(HospitalsActivity.this);
...
```

crash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutInclude2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
         >

        <include layout="@layout/crash_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gp_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/xyzs"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.exampleApp.utils.MyEditText
        android:id="@+id/searchedittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_xyz"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

<ProgressBar
             android:id="@+id/globalprogressBar"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:visibility="gone"/>
     <com.exampleApp.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/xyzListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        ptr:ptrShowIndicator="false"
        android:scrollbars="none" 
        android:visibility="visible">
    </com.exampleApp.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>

      <ListView
                android:id="@+id/globalListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/searchLayout"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutNoNetWork"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoNetwork"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/No_Network"
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoNetworkDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/No_NetworkDesc"
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/default_ptr_rotate"
            android:text="Refresh"
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNoResultFound"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/No_ResultFound"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

crash_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tab_top_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@color/white"
     android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/layoutLocation"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/tab_title_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tab_title_margin"
            >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/screen_header"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tab_title_sz" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tab_title_margin"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/midtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
            android:text=" - "
            android:textColor="@color/screen_header"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tab_subtitle_sz"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/midtitle"
            android:text="Sub title"
            android:textColor="@color/screen_header"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tab_subtitle_sz"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_top_layout" 
         android:background="@color/white"
        android:weightSum="100"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tab_bottom_layout_padding"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/tab_bottom_layout_padding"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/xyz"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="22" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/xyz_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/xyz_iv"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="xyzS"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tab_txt_name_size"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/xyz_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/xyz_off" />

             <View
                 android:id="@+id/xyz_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@color/screen_header"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/xyz_tv" 
                 android:visibility="invisible"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/abc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="22" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/abc_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_off" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abc_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/abc_iv"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="abcS"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tab_txt_name_size"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin" />

             <View
                 android:id="@+id/abc_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@color/screen_header"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/abc_tv"
                  android:visibility="invisible" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/deals"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="22"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deals_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/deals_off" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/deals_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/deals_iv"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="HEALTHY DEALS"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tab_txt_name_size"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/deals_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@color/screen_header"
                android:layout_below="@+id/deals_tv"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/screen_logo" 
             android:layout_weight="12"/>





            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="22" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_off" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_iv"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="PROFILE"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tab_txt_name_size"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tab_txt_name_margin"/>

             <View
                 android:id="@+id/profile_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@color/screen_header"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/profile_tv" 
                  android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height=".5dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@color/gary_light" 
                         android:layout_below="@+id/tab_bottom_layout"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add your activity code and check xml file name is proper or not.

Comment: @Androidjack I have added the snippet of the code where the crash was reported, also the XML name is correct. It has been working smoothly, otherwise how would it work on the other thousands of devices.

Comment: What kind of device is reporting the error? Please provide your directory structure (e.g. are there any special resources for other locales). Which version of android is running on the device?

Comment: @JonasKöritz layouts are placed in the default layout folder which in my case would be exampleApp/src/main/res/layout . There are no other folders for layouts.
The device on which it has been reported is an IBall AudiHD with android version 4.4.2

Comment: can you post your crash_screen.xml file.

Comment: and crash_layout.xml too

Comment: @Androidjack crash_screen.xml has been added

Comment: @JonasKöritz crash_layout.xml has been added.

Comment: delete the build folder in the app folder in android studio and then rebuild the project

Comment: @Androidjack I can do that....But how will it make any difference in the Playstore version of the app...The user downloaded my app using Playstore  and reported it once in Developer console Crash ANR...

Comment: such issues are related with build process which are resolved by cleaning the project.Before uploading it to play store you need to make sure to resolve such build related issues.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: It has been working. It never stopped working. I just wanted to know and correct the root cause of this particular crash in this device.

Comment: if it crashed on only a particular device the problem might be different.